# Appcelerator | 'Android Distribution' Android SDK version 4.1.2 not found

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have pulled an Appcelerator project from our developer group and unable to publish or run the project on a local Android device. 
When trying to publish the below error screen immediately pops up. 
[Android SDK version 4.1.2 not found.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOEz4.png)

I have checked both in the Appcelerator platform settings and Android Studio config and have the SDK installed.[The install SDK screen in Appcelerator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JEIH.png) Tried uninstalling/reinstalling Appcli and the SDK to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a few days of searching all the appecelerator files in my project. I finally found the fix for my problem (for anyone googling this).

There's a hidden file in the root of the Appcli project called `.settings`

Inside of settings there's a package called `com.appcelerator.titanium.android.core.prefs`

There is an `android/sdk_version=4.1.2` that was causing all my issues. Hope that helps someone.

Comment: Hi,
I get same error and followed your steps but there is not any version set as you stated so what could be an issue now?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, your issue seems to be with unsupported Android SDK version as per Ti SDK you are using.

So before doing anything, try to grab what this page says to know all about software compatibilities: **[Titanium Comptability Matrix](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Titanium_Compatibility_Matrix-section-src-29004837_safe-id-VGl0YW5pdW1Db21wYXRpYmlsaXR5TWF0cml4LUFuZHJvaWRTREsvVGFyZ2V0QW5kcm9pZFBsYXRmb3Jt)**

It says that minimum Android version as of latest Ti SDK 6.x.x is API 16.

Now, follow these steps carefully to get a fresh start on your system.

1. First of all, download Android latest SDK from here: **[Android SDK](http://www.in.techspot.com/downloads/development/android-sdk-24-0-2/articleshow/47635066.cms)**
2. Unzip it & put it in at some simple path like in */Users/username/android-sdk*
3. Download **Appcelerator Studio (AS)** & install it. It will download all pre-requisites like Java, Python
4. Open Appcelerator Studio & go to **Preferences->Studio->Platforms->Android**. Select the path of android sdk you unzipped in step 2.

After all these steps, you can open Android SDK Manager (see screenshot where it is) & install necessary SDK, Tools, etc.

[image]

**Note:** I do not suggest to download SDKs via AS as I have faced path issues in beginning.

---

Even if these steps do not help you, then provide us the log output after running this command on terminal: **`appc info`**

If terminal says this command is not found, then you need to go through the AS installation properly.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not fix the error screen when publishing. The appc info command also recognizes that SDK 4.1.2 is located in the correct folder. 
3) android-16
    Name                      = Android 4.1.2 **Not supported by Titanium SDK 6.2.0.GA**
    API Level                 = 16
    Revision                  = 1
    Skins                     = HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800, WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in
    ABIs                      = armeabi-v7a, x86
    Path                      = /Users/rob.meyers/Library/android-sdk-macosx/platforms/android-16

Comment: I also ensured that any <min-sdk> in the tiapp.xml and the am.txt started at Android 2. The error log gives me no clues either. !ENTRY com.appcelerator.titanium.android.core 4 0 2017-09-19 10:17:02.409
!MESSAGE Android SDK version 4.1.2 not found.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Simply deleting all " Android Play Store Distribution" configurations solved my problem.